# Count and group by with mongo db

Tags: mongodb

I m actually facing a problem with mongoDB.

I need to display some statistics :
- A treatment is an information that contain a date, the user who treated, a list of anomalies

Can you help me with the request to get :

"The numbers of anomalies by users ?"

Thanks for all :D

Answer (score 0):

```
db.treatment.aggregate(
  { 
      $group : {_id : "$anomalies", totalUser : { $sum : 1 }}
  }
);
```

Note : change your `collection` and document `key name` if I put wrong.

Source : http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-aggregate-and-group-example/

Comment: It works great to count users for anomalies but what I need is to display : user 1 => 50 anomalies, user 2 =>60 anomalies, user 3 =>10 anomalies

Comment: I gave you query for group by anomalies. If you want query for group by user then try with `$user` instead of `$anomalies`.

Comment: J actually trying to make it work. But I ll need time I think /:

Answer (score 0):

So,  if your collection had the following documents:

```
> db.treatments.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "date" : ISODate("2014-08-29T15:44:45.843Z"), "user" : "A", "anomalies" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "date" : ISODate("2014-08-29T15:45:01.782Z"), "user" : "A", "anomalies" : [ "e", "f", "g" ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "date" : ISODate("2014-08-29T15:45:34.889Z"), "user" : "B", "anomalies" : [ "a", "b", "c", "e", "f", "g" ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "date" : ISODate("2014-08-29T15:48:01.860Z"), "user" : "B", "anomalies" : [ "a", "b", "c", "e", "f", "g" ] }
{ "_id" : 5, "date" : ISODate("2014-08-29T15:48:28.937Z"), "user" : "A", "anomalies" : [ "x", "y", "z" ] }
```

You can use $group stage to $sum the $size  of the anomalies array

```
> db.treatments.aggregate([ { $group: { _id: "$user", allAnomalies: { $sum: { $size: "$anomalies" } } } } ] )
{ "_id" : "B", "allAnomalies" : 12 }
{ "_id" : "A", "allAnomalies" : 9 }
```